# How does the NotificationCenter work in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsnotificationcenter

I was wondering that how actually the NotificationCenter work in iOS SDK? We all know that we can `addObserver` to `NSNotificationCenter`. This might be storing `@selector` and `target` based on it's name given in the method.

It might be calling like:

```
 [target performSelector:selector withObject:specifiedObject];
```

I want to know that how iOS manage to store these target, selector and object and map it with the name. Also how it broadcast the notification, because there may be multiple objects having same notification name registered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388309/how-nsnotification-works